# Scala: Performing comparision on query output

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare count of 2 different queries/tables. Is it possible to perform this operation in Scala(Spark SQL)?

Here is my code:

```
val parquetFile1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/njrbars2/ars/mbr_addr/2016/2016_000_njars_09665_mbr_addr.20161222031015221601.parquet") 
val parquetFile2 =sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/njrbars2/ars/mbr_addr/2017/part-r-00000-70ce4958-57fe-487f-a45b-d73b7ef20289.snappy.parquet")
parquetFile1.registerTempTable("parquetFile1")
parquetFile2.registerTempTable("parquetFile2")

scala> var first_table_count=sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from parquetFile1")
first_table_count: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: bigint]

scala> var second_table_count=sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from parquetFile1 where LINE1_ADDR is NULL and LINE2_ADDR is NULL")
second_table_count: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: bigint]

scala> first_table_count.show()
+------+
|   _c0|
+------+
|119928|
+------+

scala> second_table_count.show()
+---+
|_c0|
+---+
|617|
+---+
```

I am trying to get difference value of both these queries but getting error.

```
scala> first_table_count - second_table_count
<console>:30: error: value - is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
              first_table_count - second_table_count
```

whereas if I do normal substraction, it works

```
scala> 2 - 1
res7: Int = 1
```

It seems I have to do some data conversion but not able to find appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer version of spark count not return Long value instead it is reaped inside dataframe object i.e. Dataframe[BigInt].

you can try this

```
val diffrence = first_table_count.first.getLong(0) - second_table_count.first.getLong(0);
```

And subtract method is not available on dataframe.

Comment: Don't forget to upward this answer

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following to do the conversion:

```
first_table_count.first.getLong(0)
```

And here is why you need it:
A DataFrame represents a tabular data structure. So although your SQL seems to return a single value, it actually returns a table containing a single row, and the row contains a single column. Hence we use the above code to extract the first column (index 0) of the first row.

Comment: Thanks Hakan for explaining this. I can understand now where I was doing it wrong. Thanks again..